# Solr suggester filter at build time

Tags: solr

Is it possible to create a suggestion dictionary using a pre-filtered query ? In other word is it possible to create a suggestion dictionary based on a subset of an existing index instead of the whole index ?

This is a feature very similar to context filtering, but beforehand.

In my case, I'd like to create a suggestion dictionary using semi-public data only (not owned by a tenant) and language, from my main index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no that is not possible right now. I see 3 possible ways to do what you want:

1. you create a new collection from scratch, indexing from the original source only the subset you want in a field, and use that field as DocumentDictionaryFactory for the suggester
2. again, create a new index, but index it off the existing collection, either using [DIH and the SolrEntityProcessor](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#SolrEntityProcessor) or with with [Streaming expressions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions#StreamingExpressions-update)
3. you create your custom FilteredDocumentDictionaryFactory that does what you need and plug it in into Solr.